# Script to copy data from one sheet to another based on criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet called the master list. It contains two sheets 'Response' and 'Master Response'. The response sheet has around 3000 rows of data and the first column in the 'response' sheet is called ' responded?'. I want to copy the row from 'response' sheet to ' master response' sheet if the 'responded?' column has the value 'called' in it and every time a new entry is made in the 'response' sheet the appropriate row of data should be copied to the 'master response' sheet. I am currently using the following code but the rows get moved from the 'Response' sheet and not copied. I wanted a script where the rows are copied to the 'Master response' sheet and should also stay on the ' response' sheet.
Thank you in advance.

```
function onEdit() 
{
var sheetNameToWatch = "Response";
var columnNumberToWatch = 1;
var valueToWatch = "Called";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Master Response";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == 
columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch)
{
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 
sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `copyTo` instead of `moveTo` to copy the data from one sheet to another.

```
sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
```

To Copy it to different Spreadsheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<SPREADSHEET ID>>").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var newTargetRange = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(newTargetRange);
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply. The code works fine in term of copying the data. But instead of copying the particular row it copies the entire sheet. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Comment: change the range according....`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`...here `sheet.getLastRow()` will give the last number

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. the code works fine now. Is it possible to modify the code to copy the rows to another worksheet by id? By that, I mean that now I want to copy the results in another sheet of the same workbook and also to a sheet in another workbook. I tried modifying it but got stuck.

Comment: I tried using ur edited code to copy row to a different workbook but an error is being displayed saying    [var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();] (function cannot be found)